# Avoid dictionary to be overwritten every iteration

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```py
G = {1: [[2, 3], [3, 22], [5, 4]], 2: [[1, 3], [3, 5]], 3: [[2, 3], [1, 22], [5, 20], [4, 9]], 5: [[1, 2], [3, 20], [4, 4]],
     4: [[3, 9], [5, 4]]}
V = {1: 5, 2: 17, 3: 8, 4: 3, 5: 1}
N=2
for i in range(N):
    x=int(input())
    y=int(input())
    for i in range(1,6):
        if i != x:
            if i != y:
                for vertex in V:
                    for node, edges in G.items():
                        if i == vertex:
                            if node == vertex:
                                for weight in edges:
                                    weight[1] += V[vertex]
```

I want the dictionary `G` to remain the same every time I iterate in the first loop. However, `G` gets overwritten every time I iterate, hence I get the wrong output. What should I add/modify to my code so that `G` remains the same after each iteration of the first for loop?

For reference, here are my outputs and the output I want:

```
output1: {1: [[2, 8], [3, 27], [5, 9]], 2: [[1, 3], [3, 5]], 3: [[2, 11], [1, 30], [5, 28], [4, 17]], 5: [[1, 3], [3, 21], [4, 5]], 4: [[3, 9], [5, 4]]}

(WRONG) output2: {1: [[2, 8], [3, 27], [5, 9]], 2: [[1, 20], [3, 22]], 3: [[2, 11], [1, 30], [5, 28], [4, 17]], 5: [[1, 4], [3, 22], [4, 6]], 4: [[3, 12], [5, 7]]}

(CORRECT) output2: {1: [[2, 3], [3, 22], [5, 4]], 2: [[1, 20], [3, 22]], 3: [[2, 3], [1, 22], [5, 20], [4, 9]], 5: [[1, 3], [3, 21], [4, 5]], 4: [[3, 12], [5, 7]]}
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: It looks like the only purpose of most of this code is to change `G`. Why are you doing any of this if you don't want to change `G`?

Comment: And why are you iterating over `V` and `G.items()` at all when you only care about the specific entries `V[i]` and `G[i]`? You could just look up `V[i]` and `G[i]` directly.

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer so I'm just coding what I know for now.

Comment: You CORRECT output is the same as the input dictionary. So basically all the code in the middle has no meaning and you can just output the input? Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `from copy import deepcopy` to your import statements, and then at the start of the loop where you want a fresh copy of G to work with write `G_copy = deepcopy(G)` and then instead of `G.items()` use `G_copy.items()`

Though as others have pointed out - unless you add more code here this will be pointless, as you'll be throwing away the results after each loop unless you make use of all the new `G_copy`s somewhere.

Comment: It'd be easier and more efficient to just move the `G = ...` initialization into the loop.

Comment: Yes, if you're free to just move the initialization code for G inside the for loop, that would be simplest (no need for deepcopy). But that may not fit the requirements (you wouldn't then have access to G outside the for loop).

Comment: @J.J. Why not? A `for` loop doesn't have its own naming scope

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. This is actually just a part of a huge program I'm working on so as long as this problem is fixed, it's okay.

Comment: @starglitter No it's not OK because SO is not a private help-desk and your question remains unclear. Please clarify so it has value for the site or just delete it

Comment: @Tomerikoo yep, my mistake - in the specific case, yes G will still be accessible outside of the loop. - I just figured OP was doing some other things with G behind the scenes not written here, since otherwise repeatedly overwriting seems pointless.